# Python tkinter click event not processed

Tags: python, search, tkinter, click

I wrote the Python tkinter script below.
For some reason the click event doesn't react: I would like the radiobuttons to switch when I select the other entry, but the click function is not executed. I do not understand why not.

I think the binding is OK ?

Anyone who sees what I'm doing wrong ?

All the details are in the code

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class PyExplore(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None, dataframes = None):
        # Construct the Frame object.
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        # Bind click event
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        # Place the main frame on the grid
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        # Store dataframes
        self.dataframes = dataframes
        # Create widgets
        self.createWidgets()

    # Callback function - Clicked somewhere
    def click(self, event):
        print(self.focus_get())

        if self.focus_get() == self.entryY:
            self.selectedVar.set('Y')
        elif self.focus_get() == self.entryX:
            self.selectedVar.set('X')

    def createWidgets(self):  
        # Get top window 
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        # Make it stretchable         
        self.top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Make certain rows and columns stretchable
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)        
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create frameSelection
        self.frameSelection = ttk.Frame(self, relief='ridge', borderwidth=4)
        # Make frameSelection stretchable
        self.frameSelection.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.frameSelection.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Y, X labels
        self.selectedVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.selectedVar.set('Y')
        self.radiobuttonY = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frameSelection, text='Y       ', variable=self.selectedVar, value='Y')
        self.radiobuttonY.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW, padx =1, pady=1)
        self.radiobuttonX = ttk.Radiobutton(self.frameSelection, text='X       ', variable=self.selectedVar, value='X')
        self.radiobuttonX.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW, padx =1, pady=1)


        # Y, X entries
        self.entryY = ttk.Entry(self.frameSelection)
        self.entryY.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW, padx =1, pady=1)
        self.entryX = ttk.Entry(self.frameSelection)
        self.entryX.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky = tk.NE + tk.SW, padx =1, pady=1)


        self.frameSelection.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

# Allow the class to run stand-alone.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PyExplore().mainloop()
```

Comment: This question is too broad, with too much code. Please try to narrow down your question to a single problem, with a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
self.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
```

with:

```
self.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.click)
```

As clicking on a child of a widget doesn't necessarily mean that parent widget has the focus too apparently.

Comment: binding to click events is unaffected by which widget has focus.

Comment: @lvdp Well, thank yourself and [Bryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079022/python-tkinter-click-event-not-processed/48083291?noredirect=1#comment83132137_48079022). When the code was simplified it was much easier to understand.